# How to save or update OneToMany Column with value Null in JPA (Using Play Framework)

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate, jpa, playframework-2.0

I'm currently developing a system using PLAY framework and JPA. My problem is that I can't save an EMPLOYEE if Department_id (which is connected to another Entity class) is Null or has no value.

Here is my Employees Entity Class

```
 @Entity
 public class Employees{

        @Id
        public int employee_id;
        public String first_name;
        public String last_name;
        public String email;
        public String phone_number;
        public java.sql.Date hire_date;
        public String salary;
        public String commission_pct;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="department_id",nullable = true)
        private Departments department_id;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="job_id")
        private Jobs job_id;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="manager_id",nullable = true)
        private Employees manager_id;
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "manager_id")
        Set<Employees> emps = new HashSet<Employees>();
    }
```

Here is my Departments Entity Class.

```
@Entity
public class Departments {

    @Id
    private String department_id;
    private String department_name;
    private int manager_id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="department_id")
    private Set<Employees> emps = new HashSet<Employees>();
}
```

Here is the error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved
transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: modelsDomain.E
mployees.department_id -> modelsDomain.Departments
        at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$9.noCascade(CascadingAction.java
:387) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.9.Final.jar:3.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:172) ~[hibernate-co
re-3.6.9.Final.jar:3.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.cascadeOnFlush(
AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:154) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.9.Final.jar:3.6.9.F
inal]
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFl
ushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:145) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.9.Final.jar:3
.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverything
ToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.9.Final
.jar:3.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlus
hEventListener.java:50) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.9.Final.jar:3.6.9.Final]
```

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: How do you generate your Id's? Do you save all the data manually? An additional notice, your classes should be named in singular not plural Employee and Department, because they represent one Employee or Department.

Comment: Good Day, I've already edited my question showing my error. What i wanted is to save or update an employee whether it has departments or not.

Comment: Sorry for using Employees instead of Employee same with Departments, I'm new to PLAY framework and I don't want to mess up with naming entities. Since my table name in the Database is Employees, I tried not to change the entity name in my program.

Comment: No need to fear that. It's fairly ease to use a custom name for your class. You only need to use the `@Table` annotation above your class. In your case you would do something like `@Table(name = "employees")`, now your class can have any name you like. If you're new to JPA (which you are using in the Play Framework) you should take a look at [Java Persistence Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence). Also it's a convention to use camelCase in Java and not snake_case.

Comment: Thank you for the information @kaba713 :D